# Why are my project's drawables blurry?

Tags: android

For some reason, the drawables in my app are blurry. This is especially apparent in menus when I put built-in system icons side-by-side with icons from my project's res folder.

[image: blurry project icon next to crisp system icon]

Here's an example. The left envelope icon is in my app's drawable-hdpi folder. It is scaled down, for some reason. The right one is using the built-in Android resources. As far as I can tell, they are the same 72x72px file--I copied the png straight from the drawable-hdpi folder in SDK to my project's drawable-hdpi folder.

Is there some special setting for drawables in my app that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the appropriate `supports-screens` element to your Android manifest, and make sure you have a `min-sdk` of at least 4. Also make sure your `uses-sdk` element is nested under the `manifest` and not under the `application` (if it's in the wrong place or missing, your app will still work but can cause issues with compatibility-related code like resource scaling, and will prevent uploading to the market with an obscure error... it can be a tough one to track down).

Comment: The problem was that my `min-sdk` was set to `3`. Changing it to `4` got rid of the blurriness all around (although for some reason the project icons are still smaller than the identical system ones?). Thank you!

Comment: For anyone who comes across this in the future: I also got it to work by keeping `minSdkVersion` at `3` and adding `targetSdkVersion` at a value of `4` or higher inside the `uses-sdk` tag (`8` in my case, as I'm targeting Android 2.2).

Comment: Yup. Be careful using a target-sdk higher than your min-sdk -- you can very easily accidentally call APIs that won't work on the lower SDK versions, so be sure to test thoroughly on your min-sdk as well. If your min-sdk is 3, be sure you realize that drawables in the -mdpi or -hdpi folders (as opposed to just 'drawables') can cause issues.

Comment: Figured out why the icons were still smaller: I had copied them from `android-10` (2.3) while my phone is running 2.2. Android 2.3's included menu icons actually are smaller than 2.2's -- an aesthetic change in Gingerbread, it seems.

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue for me - any takers?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an mdpi screen? If so then your device is having to take the drawables from drawables-hdpi and scale them down, which would likely cause them to blur.

You might try also copying the -mdpi resources to your drawable-mdpi folder, which would allow the framework use your drawables without adjusting for screen density.

**Edit** - now that I think about it, I'm not sure why your image would appear smaller unless your screen had a greater dpi than hdpi.

Comment: I'm using a Droid Incredible, so it's hdpi (as far as I know). I also copied over the proper mdpi resources into my project's mdpi folder, so that shouldn't be the issue.